# What term denotes "respecting dark and light themes"?

Tags: website-design, terminology

If my website displays appropriately on a wide variety of screen sizes, I would say, "My website is responsive."

In a similar spirit, if my website respects the user's choice of light theme vs dark theme and displays differently in accordance with that, I would like to say, "My website is ____." What word can I fill in this blank?

There is some nuance here in terms of how I let the user choose the theme. I can either add a toggle on my website that the user can click, or I can infer the preference from the User-Agent (`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`). Let me know if the term only applies to one of these situations, or if there are different terms for these two situations.

If there isn't a term specifically for light vs dark, is there a more general term that says that my website displays differently based on something other than just size.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary to be able to say it in the same way as "responsiveness". Would it be sufficient to say "My website supports dark mode" or "My website supports the ability for a light and dark mode"? I am really curious if someone else has a better answer :)

Comment: Saying "it supports dark mode" doesn't clarify if light mode is also supported. "It supports light and dark modes" feels verbose, but I guess I don't have other options.

Comment: @EklavyaSharma I'd think that "supports" implies that it has an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

A word for the blank:

"Adaptive" ?

Definition: an ability to change to suit changing conditions ( in this case a user lighting choice )

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common term is "Dark Mode", you can play with [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=US&q=dark%20mode,dark%20theme) to find a better wording. Using words like contrast and readability carry other meanings especially since dark mode doesn't necessarily lead to better readability, it depends on the user's disability.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive by PhillipW was an excellent answer. I'm hard pressed to offer a different one.

I might also say:

"My website respects view preferences." Which would incorporate both size AND light/dark preferences.

"My website preserves Theme." I use theme because it seems to be used around the web to refer to Light / Dark mode even though a set theme could go beyond just that.